# How to alter and display only one column (via user input) on 2D array Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am creating a game board. I need it to reveal a the selected column after a user input, while the rest of the columns still print as "X". This game holds values I have set in each column, but does not print them on the screen. When the user selects a column, I need it to print showing the value that column is holding while the rest of the columns still print "X" so they do not reveal what they have. I am new to this, thank you for your help.

---

This is the function where I think the problem is. If you look, you will see that I have the if statement "if (isCovered) - then I want it to print the covered version. Then the "else" - which is where I want it to print just the one that was guessed as its actual value. I have tried multiple ways of achieving this with no luck. Is there are way to make it like (!isCovered)? But that doesn't work, because it states it needs to be an array and the function "!" does not work. Right now it just seems like it never prints the "else" statement at all. I have functions that take the user input and compare them to "isCovered" and they work correctly, because the piece moves on the board as it should. I just cannot get it to print the actual value instead of an "X". Thank you for any help and if further information would be helpful, please let me know. It is due today unfortunately I only had a few days to work on it and have been working constantly on it.

---

```
public static void PrintRevealBoard(int[][] myArray,Boolean[][] isCovered) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<myArray.length ; i++ ) { // array.length = max rows
        System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
        for(j = 0; j <myArray[0].length; j++) { // array[0].length = max 
        cols
        if(isCovered[i][j]){
        System.out.print(GetRollColorCovered(myArray[i][j]) + " ");
         } else {
        System.out.print(GetRollColor(myArray[i][j]) + " ");
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

your main module is kinda messy. And I don't know how GetRollColor(dice) works. Anyway as I understand you have a two dimensional array and you want to show only a specific value. Seems like u want to show the entire input column.
use this to update isRevealed() after the input of inputCol.

```
public static Boolean[][] updateRevealed(Boolean[][] isRevealed, int inputCol){                                           
   for(int i=0;i<isRevealed[inputCol].length;i++)
     isRevealed[inputCol][i] = true;
   return isRevealed;
}
```

update like this,

```
isRevealed = updateRevealed(isRevealed,inputCol);
```

your printRevealBoard is almost correct. Just remove the first line. It doesn't make sense and you don't want it as I see

```
int isRevealed = inputCol;
```

I don't know how your array looks like. But because of the first for loop u will definitely get an

> index out of bounds exception

loop runs until I becomes myarray.length. and in the next loop you access index I of myArray. Exception will be thrown if I=myArray.length. u gotta fix it. If any problem  occurs lemme know.
thankyou

edit:
try this for printRevealBoard

```
    public static void printRevealBoard(char[][] myarray , Boolean[]   []isRevealed){
     for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<myarray[0].length;j++){
           if (isRevealed[i][j]) System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " ");
              else System.out.print("* ");
        }
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited my original post to explain the issues I am still having. Any help or ideas you have would be greatly appreciated

Comment: both errors are because you are parsing wrong variables to methods. In the main module, Boolean isRevealed holds every data needed to whole board. So it must be two dimensional array with lengths as same as the array of the board. This should correct the first error

Comment: Next, error says you are parsing an integer array instead of char array. In the main module you are providing an integer array for printRevealBoard.You can either make that input array a char array or change the method to get integer array as input. And this should correct the second error

Comment: I appreciate the help. It is unfortunately not working :/ I am trying to go a different route and it also is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately had to submit the assignment due to the deadline. Never got that function working correctly. Btw I did upvote your answer through because it was helpful. I think that there was just a better way to set the arrays-maybe using a different one altogether that tracked which column had to be revealed but I ran out of time. Thanks for your help!